# InfluxDB 1.7.x high CPU usage on Rasperry PI 3+

Tags: raspberry-pi3, grafana, influxdb

I've got my Raspbery PI 3+ set up to run Grafana (with InfluxDB and Telegraf) to collect network stats for home network. I read data from my Sonic Wall, a "smart managed" HP switches, and two Cisco switches. There are a few metrics for ping times and packet loss, and the machine also hosts my Unifi access point manager.

This has worked great for about 6 months. Over the last few days, InfluxDB has gotten sick. Grafana started showing 501 errors when trying to query InfluxDB. I rebooted the Pi and it came back ... but about 12 hours later I'm stuck again with 501s.

I see that InfluxDB is pegging the CPU. Never had high CPU usage, but now I'm around 200 to 250% all the time. This is puzzling since (as far as I can tell) there's no reason for the query load on the DB to have changed.

I think things got worse when I upgraded to InfluxDB 1.7.7, but I don't know what my previous version was. Further, I'm having a hard time collecting any information from InfluxDB because it pegs CPU usage as soon as it starts and the host becomes unresponsive.

How do I diagnose InfluxDBs high CPU usage?

Here is `htop` showing influxd using more than 350% CPU:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2019-07-07 13:25:02
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  1  [||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                             25.5%]   Tasks: 36, 147 thr; 6 running
  2  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                         29.5%]   Load average: 3.43 3.84 3.78
  3  [||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                             25.6%]   Uptime: 00:47:19
  4  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                   54.7%]
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                               136M/926M]
  Swp[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||99.9M/100.0M]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 4306 influxdb   20   0 1019M 48344 30068 R 121.  5.1  0:07.04 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
 4310 influxdb   20   0 1019M 48344 30068 S 16.4  5.1  0:00.43 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
 4309 influxdb   20   0 1019M 48344 30068 S 11.8  5.1  0:00.34 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
 4311 influxdb   20   0 1019M 48344 30068 S  7.2  5.1  0:00.37 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
  559 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  2.6  1.9  3:08.39 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 4270 pi         20   0  6372  3060  2072 R  2.6  0.3  0:01.06 htop
  116 root       20   0 29168  3012  2780 S  2.6  0.3  0:41.88 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
 4307 influxdb   20   0 1019M 48344 30068 S  2.0  5.1  0:00.04 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
 4312 influxdb   20   0 1019M 48344 30068 S  1.3  5.1  0:00.24 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
 1066 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 R  1.3  1.9  0:09.25 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1057 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.7  1.9  0:11.60 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  340 mongodb    20   0  232M  2492  1760 S  0.7  0.3  0:35.16 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
 1234 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.7  1.9  0:07.61 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1239 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.7  1.9  0:08.03 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  451 mongodb    20   0  232M  2492  1760 S  0.7  0.3  0:14.52 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
  345 root       20   0 23756  1036   556 S  0.7  0.1  0:11.47 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
  381 root       20   0 23756  1036   556 S  0.7  0.1  0:05.25 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
  659 unifi      20   0 1112M 20080  1832 S  0.7  2.1  0:15.78 unifi -cwd /usr/lib/unifi -home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/lib/unifi/lib/ac
  445 mongodb    20   0  232M  2492  1760 S  0.7  0.3  0:05.27 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
  721 www-data   20   0  224M   384   332 S  0.7  0.0  0:01.90 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  684 www-data   20   0  224M   384   332 S  0.7  0.0  0:01.90 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  756 unifi      20   0 1112M 20080  1832 S  0.7  2.1  0:02.29 unifi -cwd /usr/lib/unifi -home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/lib/unifi/lib/ac
  765 grafana    20   0  924M 13820  3420 S  0.7  1.5  0:00.45 /usr/sbin/grafana-server --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini --pidfile=/var/run/grafana/grafana-server.pid cfg:default.paths.logs=/var/log/
  671 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.0  1.9  0:11.24 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 3627 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.0  1.9  0:01.78 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  740 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.0  1.9  0:07.68 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  663 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.0  1.9  0:20.88 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1081 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.0  1.9  0:14.85 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1248 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.0  1.9  0:12.42 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  666 root       20   0  916M  5004  1464 S  0.0  0.5  0:00.35 /usr/bin/containerd
 4181 grafana    20   0  924M 13820  3420 S  0.0  1.5  0:00.03 /usr/sbin/grafana-server --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini --pidfile=/var/run/grafana/grafana-server.pid cfg:default.paths.logs=/var/log/
 1241 telegraf   20   0  832M 18420  7440 S  0.0  1.9  0:07.99 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  667 root       20   0  916M  5004  1464 S  0.0  0.5  0:00.43 /usr/bin/containerd
F1Help  F2Setup F3SearchF4FilterF5Tree  F6SortByF7Nice -F8Nice +F9Kill  F10Quit



-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2019-07-07 13:25:02
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  1  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                           28.0%]   Tasks: 36, 147 thr; 3 running
  2  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                                 39.5%]   Load average: 3.57 3.85 3.79
  3  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                   53.9%]   Uptime: 00:47:45
  4  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                76.3%]
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                     310M/926M]
  Swp[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||99.4M/100.0M]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 4306 influxdb   20   0 1972M  314M  123M S 189. 34.0  1:08.90 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
 4316 influxdb   20   0 1972M  314M  123M R 99.5 34.0  0:14.78 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
 4313 influxdb   20   0 1972M  314M  123M S 35.6 34.0  0:09.87 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
 4314 influxdb   20   0 1972M  314M  123M S 27.7 34.0  0:10.05 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
  559 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  4.0  2.0  3:10.10 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  740 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  3.3  2.0  0:07.75 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 4270 pi         20   0  6372  3060  2072 R  2.0  0.3  0:01.62 htop
  340 mongodb    20   0  232M  3192  2460 S  1.3  0.3  0:35.51 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
  663 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.7  2.0  0:21.13 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  451 mongodb    20   0  232M  3192  2460 S  0.7  0.3  0:14.66 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
 4307 influxdb   20   0 1972M  314M  123M S  0.7 34.0  0:00.20 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
  445 mongodb    20   0  232M  3192  2460 S  0.7  0.3  0:05.32 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
 1248 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:12.55 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1250 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:12.64 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  664 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:09.70 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1241 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:08.22 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  542 root       20   0  929M  7600  1052 S  0.0  0.8  0:04.49 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://
 3131 pi         20   0 11664   920   644 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.30 sshd: pi@pts/0
  764 unifi      20   0 1112M 20212  1832 R  0.0  2.1  0:04.79 unifi -cwd /usr/lib/unifi -home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/lib/unifi/lib/ac
 2910 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:04.93 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1057 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:11.69 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1234 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:07.79 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1236 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:13.93 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  671 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:11.35 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 1066 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:09.36 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  116 root       20   0 29168  3012  2780 S  0.0  0.3  0:42.06 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
 1239 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:08.07 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
 3627 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:01.80 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  676 root       20   0  929M  7600  1052 S  0.0  0.8  0:00.47 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://
  659 unifi      20   0 1112M 20212  1832 S  0.0  2.1  0:15.84 unifi -cwd /usr/lib/unifi -home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/lib/unifi/lib/ac
 1081 telegraf   20   0  832M 19016  7712 S  0.0  2.0  0:14.87 /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
  345 root       20   0 23756  1036   556 S  0.0  0.1  0:11.52 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
  543 grafana    20   0  924M 13820  3420 S  0.0  1.5  0:06.82 /usr/sbin/grafana-server --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini --pidfile=/var/run/grafana/grafana-server.pid cfg:default.paths.logs=/var/log/
```

In this state, I can't even run the influx CLI:

```
 $ influx
Failed to connect to http://localhost:8086: Get http://localhost:8086/ping: dial tcp [::1]:8086: connect: connection refused
Please check your connection settings and ensure 'influxd' is running.
```

I found out that influxdb now uses journald, so the logs are given by `sudo journalctl -u influxdb.service`.  I've updated the question with what I've found so far.

Turns out that influxdb doesn't write a log file; it uses journald.

Dumping the journal shows that the service is very rapidly starting up, starting to do some compacting, then running out of memory. When that happens, it shuts down ... then restarts.

```
Jul 14 02:31:43 twang influxd[4139]: ts=2019-07-14T01:31:43.096464Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcXWe5l000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcXZGU0000 op_name=ts
Jul 14 02:31:43 twang influxd[4139]: ts=2019-07-14T01:31:43.096497Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcXWe5l000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcXZGU0000 op_name=ts
Jul 14 02:31:43 twang influxd[4139]: ts=2019-07-14T01:31:43.096198Z lvl=info msg="TSM compaction (start)" log_id=0GcXWe5l000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcXZGU0001 op_
Jul 14 02:31:43 twang influxd[4139]: ts=2019-07-14T01:31:43.097520Z lvl=info msg="Beginning compaction" log_id=0GcXWe5l000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcXZGU0001 op_na
Jul 14 02:31:43 twang influxd[4139]: ts=2019-07-14T01:31:43.097611Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcXWe5l000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcXZGU0001 op_name=ts
Jul 14 02:31:43 twang influxd[4139]: ts=2019-07-14T01:31:43.097652Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcXWe5l000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcXZGU0001 op_name=ts
Jul 14 02:31:43 twang influxd[4139]: ts=2019-07-14T01:31:43.097691Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcXWe5l000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcXZGU0001 op_name=ts
Jul 14 02:31:43 twang influxd[4139]: ts=2019-07-14T01:31:43.097726Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcXWe5l000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcXZGU0001 op_name=ts
:
:
:
Jul 14 01:55:08 twang influxd[1756]: ts=2019-07-14T00:55:08.256884Z lvl=info msg="TSM compaction (start)" log_id=0GcVQfaG000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcVTIt0000 op_
Jul 14 01:55:08 twang influxd[1756]: ts=2019-07-14T00:55:08.288481Z lvl=info msg="Beginning compaction" log_id=0GcVQfaG000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcVTIt0000 op_na
Jul 14 01:55:08 twang influxd[1756]: ts=2019-07-14T00:55:08.290445Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcVQfaG000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcVTIt0000 op_name=ts
Jul 14 01:55:08 twang influxd[1756]: ts=2019-07-14T00:55:08.292220Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcVQfaG000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcVTIt0000 op_name=ts
Jul 14 01:55:08 twang influxd[1756]: ts=2019-07-14T00:55:08.293889Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcVQfaG000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcVTIt0000 op_name=ts
Jul 14 01:55:08 twang influxd[1756]: ts=2019-07-14T00:55:08.295738Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcVQfaG000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcVTIt0000 op_name=ts
Jul 14 01:55:08 twang influxd[1756]: ts=2019-07-14T00:55:08.297635Z lvl=info msg="Compacting file" log_id=0GcVQfaG000 engine=tsm1 tsm1_strategy=full tsm1_optimize=false trace_id=0GcVTIt0000 op_name=ts
Jul 14 01:55:11 twang influxd[1756]: [httpd] ::1 - username [14/Jul/2019:01:55:10 +0100] "POST /write?consistency=any&db=telegraf HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "telegraf" 07902d7a-a5d2-11e9-8001-b827eb6b4e27 11
Jul 14 01:55:11 twang influxd[1756]: [httpd] ::1 - - [14/Jul/2019:01:55:10 +0100] "POST /write?db=telegraf HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "Telegraf/1.11.1" 079a21ac-a5d2-11e9-8002-b827eb6b4e27 1683504
Jul 14 01:55:12 twang influxd[1756]: [httpd] ::1 - username [14/Jul/2019:01:55:11 +0100] "POST /write?consistency=any&db=telegraf HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "telegraf" 08451343-a5d2-11e9-8003-b827eb6b4e27 17
Jul 14 01:55:12 twang influxd[1756]: [httpd] ::1 - - [14/Jul/2019:01:55:11 +0100] "POST /write?db=telegraf HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "Telegraf/1.11.1" 089bdbca-a5d2-11e9-8004-b827eb6b4e27 1182542
Jul 14 01:55:17 twang influxd[1756]: runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 8192-byte block (540016640 in use)
Jul 14 01:55:17 twang influxd[1756]: fatal error: out of memory
Jul 14 01:55:17 twang influxd[1756]: runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 8192-byte block (540016640 in use)
Jul 14 01:55:17 twang influxd[1756]: fatal error: out of memory
```

Now, I have to figure out how to bail myself out of this mess. Any guesses?

Comment: How often are you doing the writes to influxdb? You might have to eliminate the possible problem one at a time. Maybe start with backing up the db and start with a fresh database, if it is still slow maybe your program is smashing it with too much writes? Another possibility is that it has been smashed with too much reads. Check the influxdb logs to see what is causing the intesity.

Comment: @SamuelToh, I don't have a program Grafana is doing reads when i view my dashboard; and Telegraf is reading status from my network devices. It's configured to go once per minute for 5 devices, and each device might have 40 data points. That's just 200 data points per minute.

Comment: You may have a problem with high cardinality data (= all tag values don't fit to the memory). Check cardinality of each used tag.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same like mentioned in djsomi's reply, however, for influxDB v1.8 I ended up with

1. reducing the max cpus for influxdb (see [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/config/#gomaxprocs-environment-variable))
2. and increasing the health check sleep

I got the exec file the service is using

```
sudo systemctl status influxdb
```

then editing the script

```
sudo vim /usr/lib/influxdb/scripts/influxd-systemd-start.sh
```

by adding the marked lines

```
GOMAXPROCS=1 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf $INFLUXD_OPTS & ## <- added GOMAXPROCS=1
...
while [ "$result" != "200" ]; do
  sleep 6 ## <- increased here
  result=$(curl -k -s -o /dev/null $url -w %{http_code})
  max_attempts=$(($max_attempts-1))
  if [ $max_attempts -le 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to reach influxdb $PROTOCOL endpoint at $url"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason my solution was to stop service, start influxd by hand, let it run for a while, and high cpu load went. :D